# Positional comparison in php

Tags: php, comparison

I found in some code snippets something like (the code itself is not important):

```
if (FALSE === ($thisVariable = $thisOtherVariable)) { ... }
```

Whereas Im used to do it the other way around:

```
if (($thisVariable = $thisOtherVariable) === FALSE) { ... }
```

And I'm just wondering if there is a difference/benefit about using one of the two ways.

Thanks

Comment: both are same as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no benefit from that. Both are logically the same. It's just a type of a coding convention because some prgrammers think that it has a better readability for them. I prefer the (oldskool) style `$a === FALSE` as you

Note that [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) is a powerful tool to check your code against various coding conventions like PEAR, Zend, ... You can also modify them or create your own convention using xml files and a variable rule framework. This will boost the quality and the visual quality of your code! (while it is fun :)

Comment: Having the constant first reminds me of how Yoda speaks :) "If false equals, your variable does"

Comment: @Dale I'm not a native speaker. Unfortunately I don't get this :| ... (would like)

Comment: Well most of the time we would say "Does this equals false" which sounds very natural, Yoda (from starwars) might say "False, my variable is" which is awkward and funny :)

Comment: You should consider to answer this, as it's the first explanation apart from personally preferences, that I got for this question! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Moreover, you can reduce the code to

```
if (!($this->result_id = $this->simple_query($sql)))
```

As hek2mgl wrote I prefer using false on right side :) which is right ;P heh

there are good code conventions for php

- [Zend Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html)(Check paragraph If/Else/Elseif)
- [PEAR Conventions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)

Comment: Thanks, but the code itself is not important in this case, I'm just wondering about the syntaxe

Comment: You're welcome :) it's very good to follow conventions I hate when someone tries to invent some new ones instead of following the existing.

Comment: @RobertPodwika Tell that to the guy that came up with the convention :)